# import image to picture box from desktop user

Tags: vb.net

I want to import  a picture from folder  which created by project when installed on user desktop but each user have different user name , how can i import from picture from dsektop user

Here is My code

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                Handles Button2.Click
      PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "New folder") \" + ID.Text + ".png")
 end sub
```

Comment: Please remove double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

this will resolve to the desktop folder for the current user. Are you really creating folders on the desktop?  Usually data and subfolders are stored in AppData.

**EDIT**

I SUSPECT you might have need of this folder in other places and even if not it can be saved and 'fixed' before hand.  Elsewhere, like when the app starts:

```
Friend mUserFolder As String
mUserFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
' your code was not adding the required backslash
mUserFolder &= "\Data\"           ' append the sub folder name
```

Now to load the file in button click the code is simpler to read and debug:

```
 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(muserFolder & ID.Text & ".png")
```

Also use `&` for concatenating strings instead of `+`

Comment: yes i'm create folder on desktop ... please can you copy my code above and edit it ... then post it please

Comment: please now i want to check if files exist in this folder or not

Comment: Click the check up next to your question to mark this problem as fixed.  Then ask a new question for the new problem...I dont know what your code looks like now.